# Is there any way to make a Plotly scatter have smooth lines connecting points?

Tags: plotly

I want to use something like a [Plotly Scatter](https://plot.ly/python/line-and-scatter/#line-and-scatter-plots) to plot my data, but I want to make the lines smooth. The only place I could think to look is at the [Mode](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scatterternary-mode) parameter.

If I were intent on a smooth plot, would I have to inject data to smooth it out?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the 'smoothing' option within the trace object. This option takes a value between 0 and 1.3, and you have to be sure to set 'shape' to 'spline':

```
smoothTrace = {'type' : 'scatter', 'mode' : 'lines', 
'x' : [1,2,3,4,5], 'y' : [4, 6, 2, 7, 8], 'line': {'shape': 'spline', 'smoothing': 1.3}}

plotly.offline.iplot([smoothTrace])
```

I've found that the amount of smoothing that this option gives is negligible at best though. I've had more success with using the [Savitzy-Golay](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html) Filter that comes in the SciPy library. You don't need to set the 'shape' or 'smoothing' options; the filter works on the values themselves:

```
evenSmootherTrace =  {'type' : 'scatter', 'mode' : 'lines', 
'x' : scipy.signal.savgol_filter([1,2,3,4,5], 51, 3), 
'y' : [4, 6, 2, 7, 8]}

plotly.offline.iplot([evenSmootherTrace])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you point to the part of documentation on Plotly website, that explains this?

Comment: The answer will cause an error, the correct syntax would be:
`smoothTrace = {'type': 'scatter', 'mode': 'lines', 
'x': [1,2,3,4,5], 'y': [4, 6, 2, 7, 8], 'line': {'shape': 'spline', 
'smoothing': 1.3}}`

Comment: @Maximillian - thanks for clearing up that oversight, much appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = np.array([1, 3, 2, 3, 1])

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y + 5, name="spline",
                    text=["tweak line smoothness<br>with 'smoothing' in line object"],
                    hoverinfo='text+name',
                    line_shape='spline'))
```

Comment: This is for sure the most simple and effective solution for conventional smoothing

Comment: Is there any way to add the smoothing factor to spline here?

Comment: @greysou1  https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.scatter.html#plotly.graph_objects.scatter.Line 
 add ```line = {'smoothing': x})``` where x is between [0,1.3] below line_shape

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I've also found out that we can add smoothing using line_smoothing

`line_smoothing=1.3`

Comment: Just to add that you can generate a scatter plot with `px.scatter` and use the following line to update the traces: `ff.update_traces(mode='lines + markers',line_shape='spline')`. Note that if you are using a trendline this will include those points, which you probably don't want